# batch file not giving correct response

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file that I need to check for the presence of a text file. If the file is detected, then it should launch an excel spreadsheet. If it doesn't detect the file, it should copy some files to various locations. It also needs to see if the version of windows is 32-bit or 64-bit

This is my batch file (not currently working correctly)

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b /s "%windir%\system32\xcopy.exe"') do set path=%path%;%%~dpa

REM check if windows 64-bit

IF EXIST "%systemdrive%\Program Files (x86)\Auto-BF\installed.txt" (
cd  "%systemdrive%\Program Files (x86)\Auto-BF"
start abf.xlsx
exit
) else (



REM check if windows 32-bit

IF EXIST "%systemdrive%\Program Files\Auto-BF\installed.txt" (
cd  "%systemdrive%\Program Files\Auto-BF"
start abf.xlsx
exit
) else (

REM create Auto-BF Folder
cd "%userprofile%\MarketFeeder Pro 7\profiles\"
md Auto-BF

REM move files_if 64-bit windows
xcopy "c:\Program Files (x86)\Auto-BF\settings.ini" "%userprofile%\MarketFeeder Pro 7\profiles\Auto-BF" /h /q /r /y
xcopy "c:\Program Files (x86)\Auto-BF\customcells.xml" "%userprofile%\MarketFeeder Pro 7\profiles\Auto-BF" /h /q /r /y
xcopy "c:\Program Files (x86)\Auto-BF\ukhorsewin.mfl" "%userprofile%\MarketFeeder Pro 7\mlocator" /h /q /r /y
xcopy "c:\Program Files (x86)\Auto-BF\auto-bf_trial.mft" "%userprofile%\MarketFeeder Pro 7\triggers" /h /q /r /y

REM move files_if 32-bit windows
xcopy "c:\Program Files\Auto-BF\settings.ini" "%userprofile%\MarketFeeder Pro 7\profiles\Auto-BF" /h /q /r /y
xcopy "c:\Program Files\Auto-BF\customcells.xml" "%userprofile%\MarketFeeder Pro 7\profiles\Auto-BF" /h /q /r /y
xcopy "c:\Program Files\Auto-BF\ukhorsewin.mfl" "%userprofile%\MarketFeeder Pro 7\mlocator" /h /q /r /y
xcopy "c:\Program Files\Auto-BF\auto-bf_trial.mft" "%userprofile%\MarketFeeder Pro 7\triggers" /h /q /r /y

ECHO Auto-BF is successfully installed - Program will now launch
PAUSE

cd "%systemdrive%\Program Files\Auto-BF\"
start abf.xlsx
EXIT
```

Comment: hasn't seemed to make any difference....I tried adding some else statements...they don't seem to work either

Comment: Which part isn't working?  Which parts do work?  What errors do you see?

Comment: You haven't added closing parenthesis for either of your `else` statements.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to try following batch file:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b /s "%windir%\system32\xcopy.exe"') do set path=%path%;%%~dpa

REM check if Windows 64-bit

IF EXIST "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Auto-BF\installed.txt" (
   cd /D "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Auto-BF"
   start abf.xlsx
   goto EndOfBatch
)

REM check if Windows 32-bit

IF EXIST "%ProgramFiles%\Auto-BF\installed.txt" (
   cd /D "%ProgramFiles%\Auto-BF"
   start abf.xlsx
   goto EndOfBatch
)

REM create Auto-BF Folder
cd /D "%userprofile%\MarketFeeder Pro 7\profiles\"
md Auto-BF

IF EXIST "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Auto-BF\*.*" (
   REM move files_if 64-bit Windows
   xcopy "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Auto-BF\settings.ini" "%userprofile%\MarketFeeder Pro 7\profiles\Auto-BF" /h /q /r /y
   xcopy "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Auto-BF\customcells.xml" "%userprofile%\MarketFeeder Pro 7\profiles\Auto-BF" /h /q /r /y
   xcopy "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Auto-BF\ukhorsewin.mfl" "%userprofile%\MarketFeeder Pro 7\mlocator" /h /q /r /y
   xcopy "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Auto-BF\auto-bf_trial.mft" "%userprofile%\MarketFeeder Pro 7\triggers" /h /q /r /y
) else (
   REM move files_if 32-bit Windows
   xcopy "%ProgramFiles%\Auto-BF\settings.ini" "%userprofile%\MarketFeeder Pro 7\profiles\Auto-BF" /h /q /r /y
   xcopy "%ProgramFiles%\Auto-BF\customcells.xml" "%userprofile%\MarketFeeder Pro 7\profiles\Auto-BF" /h /q /r /y
   xcopy "%ProgramFiles%\Auto-BF\ukhorsewin.mfl" "%userprofile%\MarketFeeder Pro 7\mlocator" /h /q /r /y
   xcopy "%ProgramFiles%\Auto-BF\auto-bf_trial.mft" "%userprofile%\MarketFeeder Pro 7\triggers" /h /q /r /y
)
ECHO Auto-BF is successfully installed - Program will now launch
PAUSE

cd /D "%ProgramFiles%\Auto-BF\"
start abf.xlsx

:EndOfBatch
```

It uses the environment variables **ProgramFiles(x86)** and **ProgramFiles** whereby the first one does not exist on machines with 32-bit Windows which results in replacing **ProgramFiles(x86)** by an empty string.

It uses the option `/D` on every **cd** command in case of current working directory is on a different drive than the directories to change to.

And it solves the main problem of your batch file: the nesting of IF commands with not correct usage of `)` by avoiding nested IF commands at all.

Your IF usage:

```
IF EXIST "%systemdrive%\Program Files (x86)\Auto-BF\installed.txt" (
   rem ...
   exit
) else (
   IF EXIST "%systemdrive%\Program Files\Auto-BF\installed.txt" (
      rem ...
      exit
   ) else (
      rem Where are the closing parentheses for the nested IF commands?
```

Last I like **1** exit point for a batch file and used therefore a **goto** command instead of **exit**.